# What is primary assembly

Tags: c#, assemblies, ilmerge

I am trying to use ILMerge in our build process.
ILMerge has the Kind enumeration, which contains the SameAsPrimaryAssembly field.
What is the this primary assembly? How can I set the primary assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ILMerge takes a set of input assemblies and merges them into one target assembly. The first assembly in the list of input assemblies is the primary assembly. When the primary assembly is an executable, then the target assembly is created as an executable with the same entry point as the primary assembly. Also, if the primary assembly has a strong name, and a .snk file is provided, then the target assembly is re-signed with the specified key so that it also has a strong name. Check this:
http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-how-to-merge-assembly/

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en

Here's how to set it:
ilmerge /out:Merged.dll /keyfile:key.snk Primary.dll Secondary.dll